# Can we use PHP iF Statements in <<<EOD syntax code

Tags: php, syntax

I am using `<<<EOD` to output some data. My question is how to use php if condition inside the `<<<EOD` syntax?
can i use it like this

```
 <<<EOD
<h3>Caption</h3>
if(isset($variablename))
{
echo "...some text";
}
else
{
echo "...some text";
}
EOD;
```

Comment: Try it. Also it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [conditional statements inside php heredocs syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012126/conditional-statements-inside-php-heredocs-syntax)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, because everything inside the `<<<` block (known as a "HEREDOC") is a string.

If you write the code in the question, you'll be writing a string containing PHP code, which isn't what you want (I hope).

Do your logic outside of the HEREDOC, and use plain variables inside it:

```
if(isset($variablename)) {
   $outputVar = "...some text";
} else {
    $outputVar = "...some text";
}

print <<<EOD
<h3>Caption</h3>
{$outputVar}
EOD;
```

Comment: Then is there any way to to use if condition with <<<EOD syntax?

Comment: @kumar - no there isn't. You would need to do the logic outside of the `<<<` block.

Comment: The heredoc syntax does allow interpolation just like when using double quotes, so whatever is inside will not necessarily come out the same as it goes in.

Comment: @DaveChen - don't know where you got that idea from. Using variables inside a `<<<` block is perfectly fine; it will work. (although not as you have it in your comment, as `<<<` blocks must be multi-line of course).

Comment: Ok thanks for help... can we use like this if(isset($var)) { <<<EOD <h3>CAPTION</h3> }

Comment: Nevermind, was thinking of something else.

Comment: i want that whole if statement to be in a variable. can we use like that?

Answer (score 9):

You can only use expressions, not statements, in double quoted strings.

There's a workaround in [complex **variable expressions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php) however. Declare a utility function beforehand, and assign it to a variable.

```
$if = function($condition, $true, $false) { return $condition ? $true : $false; };
```

Then utilize it via:

```
echo <<<TEXT

   content

   {$if(isset($var), "yes", "no")}

TEXT;
```

Comment: Just a note: this solution requires PHP >= 5.3 if you want to use an anonymous function and not a named function.

Comment: The expression syntax works with all PHP versions. The anonymous function could be displaced with a named function and plain string in the `$if` variable for PHP before 5.3. (Which is a good idea, since 5.3 just recently reached 50% server spread.)

Comment: can we use html table in <<<EOD syntax then?

Comment: @kumar: That's a different question, and can also easily be googled or evaluated by trying out.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Tested and it works! Thank you :]

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can use variable substitions

```
if(isset($variablename))
{
$var "...some text";
}
else
{
$var "...some text";
}
<<<EOD
<h3>Caption</h3>
$var
EOD;
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  Interpolation using the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax is the same as when using double quotes.  You can do simple interpolation of variables or class methods, but that's it.

This code

```
$foo = 'bar';
<<<EOD
$foo
baz($foo);
EOD;
```

will output

```
bar
baz(bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<<<EOD
<h3>Caption</h3>
EOD;
if(isset($variablename))
{
echo "...some text";
}
else
{
echo "...some text";
}
```