# Php function with php closing tag and php opening tag capture it as string

Tags: php

I like to use php function with template

Let me clarify why i want this I creating a template system that update or create view files in php dynamically.

```
function body($x = 1) { ?>
    <?php if ($x == 1) { ?>
        Congregates there is one
        ?>
        <div class="container"> Test <?= $x ?>
        <?php
    }
}?>
```

But then it just print/echo it not i want, i want can capture it as a string. There is [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or [nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) but that is not good with if, elseif, else, foreach etc. like how can i use condition here.

```
function child0($x = 4) {
    return<<<HTML
    <div class="container"> Test 
    $x
    </div> 
HTML;
}
```

[Some Old question suggesting a complicate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012126/conditional-statements-inside-php-heredocs-syntax) for using heredoc/nowdoc

Comment: `function body($x = 1) {
    if ($x == 1) {
        $str = "Congregates there is one";
        $str. ='<div class="container"> Test'.$x;
    }

    return $str;
}` . Not sure if that's what you really mean though.

Comment: _I like to use php function with template like_ Thats almost unreadable. Ween yourself off such ugly code, then you might get syntactically correct code that works :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is system that never need to take a look as we are create a file that for view php only but not intended to direct edit you will edit in our template system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the HTML section inside `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean`. Anything that is *written* to output gets buffered:

```
function body($x = 1) {
    ob_start();
    if ($x == 1) {
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            Test <?php echo $x; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Is heredoc is faster of this method trying to check them both but here doc is little tricky

Comment: Heredoc should be faster but with if and else it'll need string building e.g `if ($x) $html .= <<<HTML`